# Searching the internet for things forgotten by Google

Tags: search, google-search

I am trying to dig out information from the internet published in online forums long ago (2000ish). Over the years I have seen that most of this information has disappeared from google. Is there any way to search in the internet information no longer remembered by google?

Answer (score 1):

You can search old websites using the "Waybackmachine" at [archive.org](https://archive.org/web/).

If you are lucky you can find your forum there.